# Fetch google groups of a user using PHP. Error Domain not found

Tags: php, google-api-php-client, google-workspace, service-accounts, google-directory-api

Using the Workspace Admin SDK Directory API [groups.list](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/groups/list)
method with service account authentication.

```
$jsonKey = [
                'type' => 'service_account',
                "project_id" => "groupsnew-xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "private_key_id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "private_key" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "client_email" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "client_id" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "auth_uri" => "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
                "token_uri" => "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
                "auth_provider_x509_cert_url" => "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
                "client_x509_cert_url" => "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/goodlord%40groupsnew-1616503355252.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
            ];

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($jsonKey);
$client->setScopes(array(
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/apps.groups.settings',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.readonly',
     'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group.member.readonly',
));
$dir = new Google_Service_Directory($google_client);
$googleGroups = $dir->groups->listGroups(array(
            'domain' => 'googlegroups.com'
        ));
```

I am getting an error

```
{ "error": { "code": 404, "message": "Domain not found.", "errors": [ { "message": "Domain not found.", "domain": "global", "reason": "notFound" } ] } }
```

We are using the service account for authentication. We need to fetch all the google groups and the members in each group.

Comment: Did you set up [domain wide delegation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation) to the service account.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I am trying this API to fetch the groups created in my personal account, not any business groups. Is that an issue? The domain for the groups is 'googlegroups.com'. @DaImTo

Comment: Service accounts only work with gsuite domain accounts.  if the group isnt on the domain your not going to be able to get access to it.